# Extracting values out of serialized php array in postgresql

Tags: php, regex, postgresql

### Problem:

one column of a table contains serialized php arrays. i'd like to extract values of that serialized data structure without using php. i'd need a postgres sql statement to get those values.

### Example:

here's the part of the serialized datastructure, i'd need (the bold part):

... s:12:"SearchtermID";s:4:"**1008**"; ....

THANKS!

Comment: Take a look [here](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/JSON_datatype_GSoC_2010)

Comment: for json this will be great, for a php serialized string not so great :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work in your example:

```
SELECT substring('... s:12:"SearchtermID";s:4:"1008"; ....', 's:4:"([0-9]+)"');
```

See the manual [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html) and [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-matching.html).
You may want to provide more details ...

Comment: thanks :) this is the right trail, for my case this adaption works now. needed the name of the serialized field to filter out the right value. 


`select substring(db-fieldname from E'"php-fieldname";s:\\d+:"(\\d+)"') from db-tablename`

Answer (score 0):

This my solution:

```
select substring((regexp_matches(db_fieldname,'("\d+")','g'))[1] from '"(\d+)"') from db_tablename
```